# Why is my image appearing gray in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a project that consists of my code recognizing an image of a sudoku puzzle and then solving it. I am working on the image recognition part right now. It was working fine until I realized that I had been making the whole program flipped on the y axis. So I had replaced

```
dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width, 0], [width, height], [0, height]], dtype = "float32")
```

with

```
dimensions = np.array([[width, 0], [0, 0], [0, height], [width, height]], dtype = "float32")
```

This seemed to change everything and now that I run it I just get a grey image.
Here is my code.
Please note that I am fairly new to opencv. Also, I draw lines in my code and when I run it, the lines still appear. Just the actual image doesn't appear.

```
#Imports
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import math

#Load image
img = cv.imread('sudoku_test_image.jpeg')

#Transforms perspective
def perspectiveTransform(img, corners):
    def orderCornerPoints(corners):
        #Corners sperated into their own points
        #Index 0 = top-right
        #      1 = top-left
        #      2 = bottom-left
        #      3 = bottom-right

        #Corners to points
        corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]

        add = np.sum(corners)
        top_l = corners[np.argmin(add)]
        bottom_r = corners[np.argmax(add)]
        diff = np.diff(corners, 1)
        top_r = corners[np.argmin(diff)]
        bottom_l = corners[np.argmax(diff)]

        return (top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r)

    ordered_corners = orderCornerPoints(corners)
    top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = ordered_corners

    #Find width of new image (Using distance formula)
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    #Find height of new image (Using distance formula)
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    #Make top down view
    #Order: top-right, top-left, bottom-left, bottom-right
    dimensions = np.array([[width, 0], [0, 0], [0, height], [width, height]], dtype = "float32")

    #Make ordered_corners var numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype = 'float32')

    #Transform the perspective
    m = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    return cv.warpPerspective(img, m, (width, height))

#Processes image (Grayscale, median blur, adaptive threshold)
def processImage(img):
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv.medianBlur(gray, 3)
    thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)
    return thresh

#Find and sort contours
img_processed = processImage(img)
cnts = cv.findContours(img_processed, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv.contourArea, reverse=True)

#Perform perspective transform
peri = cv.arcLength(cnts[0], True)
approx = cv.approxPolyDP(cnts[0], 0.01 * peri, True)
transformed = perspectiveTransform(img, approx)

#Draw lines
height = transformed.shape[0]
width = transformed.shape[1]

#for vertical lines
line_x = 0
x_increment_val = round((1/9) * width)

#for horizontal lines
line_y = 0
y_increment_val = round((1/9) * height)

#vertical lines
for i in range(10):
    cv.line(transformed, (line_x, 0), (line_x, height), (0, 0, 255), 1)
    line_x += x_increment_val

#horizontal lines
for i in range(10):
    cv.line(transformed, (0, line_y), (width, line_y), (0, 0, 255), 1)
    line_y += y_increment_val

#Show image
cv.imshow('Sudoku', transformed)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my input image
[image: My input image]

Comment: It'd help to debug if you also included your input image.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added it in.

Comment: Please post your output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the input corners are wrongly calculated. Within your `perspectiveTransform` function, you have the following snippet that apparently calculates the four corners of the Sudoku puzzle:

```
    # Corners to points
    corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]

    add = np.sum(corners)
    top_l = corners[np.argmin(add)]
    bottom_r = corners[np.argmax(add)]
    diff = np.diff(corners, 1)
    top_r = corners[np.argmin(diff)]
    bottom_l = corners[np.argmax(diff)]

    return (top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r)
```

Check the `(top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r)` tuple. Those coordinates are wrong, I don't know what you are doing after computing `corners`, but the `top_l`, `bottom_r`, `top_r` and `bottom_l` calculations definitely have issues. If you hard code the tuple like this:

```
ordered_corners = [(697, 99), (108, 121), (52, 730), (735, 730)] # orderCornerPoints(corners)
```

To pass where the actual corners (starting top right, anti-clockwise) of the puzzle are, then your transformation is correct:

[image]

**Advice:** When in presence of program bugs, use the debugger and debug step by step to check the actual values of the variables and the intermediate calculations.